# Overhead of yield regarding size of yielded data

Tags: python, yield

I have a networking framework using protobuf to encode the transferred data and using `generator.send(request)` and `next_request = yield(reply)` constructs.

Now I run into performance problems where the time between `generator.send(reuqest)` and `next_request = yield(reply)` returning is nearly a second. The codebase is massive so I don't have a minimal test case. But here is the code sequence I measure:

```
data = huge_big_dictionary_of_dictionaries
logger.info("sending to generator")
generator.send(data)

# other coroutine
data = yield(...)
logger.info("got data")
```

What I get is this:

```
2021-09-13 14:16:26,427 INFO    Node    send to generator
2021-09-13 14:16:27,351 INFO    Handler got data
```

The data is a big tree where each node is a dictionary and leaves are key value pairs (strings). Top level has ~9000 entries and about a million key value pairs. It's big. The protobuf string of it is 30MiB.

Now I assumed the `send/yield` would just pass around a pointer to the structure and take practically no time. But that doesn't seem to be the case.

What does `send/yield` do? Does it make a deep_copy of the whole structure? Have to increase the reference count of every node for the garbage collector? How do I make `send/yield` run in constant time?

Comment: No, Python *never* copies implicitly like this. But is something being sent over the network by the framework? Yes, under the hood you are just sending a reference (a PyObject pointer in CPython)

Comment: The protobuf string is send over the network and recieved by the framework. Parsing the  string into python data takes about half a second and that then is send to the generator. The networking and parsing happens before the `logger.info()`.

Comment: That's the network overhead, not part of `yield` itself.

Comment: @Barmar The conversion and networking happens before the loogger.info. All the data is there and parsed before I call `generator.send`.

Comment: Which part of this sends over the network?

Comment: Well in any case, it definitely isn't the yield.

Comment: None of it. That's all outside the scope of the question and measurement. Unless I'm doing something horribly wrong I'm measuring just the code I posted. Logging before one coroutine does send and the recieving coroutine comes back from the yield.

Comment: Ahh, found the problem. I've overlooked a layer. So it's main loop -> intermediate -> generator. Each using send/yield to pass along the data. Problem was the intermediate had this code: `logger.debug("data: {0}".format(msg))` instead of `logger.debug(__("data: {0}", msg))`. The __ is a wrapper that formats the string only when it's actually displayed. The former logging call takes a second to format the string, the later never formats since debug is disabled. Sorry for the noise.